# Slices index python

Tags: python

Why when I run

```
>>> lista = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> newl = [8,10]
>>> lista[1:4] = newl
[1,8,10,5]
```

The indexes for replaced values are between 1 until 3. And when I run.

```
>>> lista[2:2] = newl
[1,2,8,10,3,4,5]
```

A new index is created to save newl.

Comment: `lista[2,2]` generates a TypeError.

Comment: no it's not, when Is assignation this create a new index

Comment: As far as I know, `lista[2,2]` is not valid Python.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Juan: Yes, it raises an error for that case too.

Comment: Are you asking why this happens?

Comment: yes, is rare, because when I run lista[2:2] it is []

Comment: No, it is not rare. That should be an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Index]

To understand slicing, you need to understand this.

Let's say

```
hi = "Hello"
```

The slice `hi[1:2]` contains `"e"`. It starts at the second character and ends before the third. `hi[2:2]` contains nothing, because it starts at the third character and ends before the third character.

If you are inserting something between characters, it is replacing it. If you do:

```
hi[1:3] = "abcd"
```

Then `"abcd"` is replacing `"el"`. This is the same with lists.

Answer (score 1):

Slice indexes are start-inclusive and end-exclusive.

`mylist[1:4]` contains the elements at indexes 1, 2, and 3.

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html:

> The slice of s from i to j is defined as the sequence of items with index k such that i <= k < j.

So if you get `mylist[2:2]` you are retrieving elements for which `2 <= k < 2` (no elements).

However, the `list` slicing syntax is clever enough to let you assign into that space, and insert elements into that position. If you run

```
mylist[2:2] = [5,6,7]
```

then you are inserting element into that space before index 2 that currently holds no elements.

Comment: Is/Was that intended?

Comment: As opposed to what? accidental?

Comment: I was curious if that behavior was intended, part of the design.

Comment: Yes. This would not be possible if people had not deliberately made it possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you tell python to replace 3 specific elements in `lista` with other 2 elements from `newl`.

In the second case you reinitialize `lista`, then you select for substitution `lista[2:2]` that is an empty list (`[]`), and more precisely the empty list *before* the 3rd element of the list (whose index is 2) and so you replace this empty list with the two values from `newl`.